# PhpStorm auto-formatting array & function woes

Tags: phpstorm, settings

I can't seem to find a way to make PhpStorm adhere to coding type for array initialization and function specification:

```php
$someArray = [
        5,
    6,
    4
];


function someFunction(
        $test,
        $test2,
) {
}
```

Note the first element of `someArray` is preceded by two tabs instead of two.
Note all parameters of the function speciation are indented by two tabs.

After running `Code -> Reformat Code` all elements and parameters are corrected and only indented by on tab, so the code style seems to be correct.

Hopefully someone here knows whether this can be solved and spare me the time looking for a solution. It's not a deal breaking problem, but it does nag me.

Thanks~!

Comment: Could you please share your code style scheme somehow? You can upload it at https://uploads.jetbrains.com/

Comment: @Dmitrii I'm using the defaults. I've uploaded my file to 2021_08_06_C3pQoxe8PqvMV92M.

Strange thing is, it's now the other way around, array values are all indented by 8 spaces, and the first parameter of the function is indented by 8, remaining parameters by 4 spaces.

Comment: The code style scheme you've shared isn't configured to use Tabs... But you have editorconfig integration enabled. Probably IDE picks up the settings from .editorconfig files & applies the formatting. If you don't have any editorconfig  files in your project - please attach a screenshot/code example that clearly illustrates the problem & how exactly do you want the code to be formatted.

Comment: It somehow magically resolved.